# adding vertical line to ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add vertical lines to a `ggplot` that displays count data per month. My x-axis is month as a factor, but my vertical lines represent Julian days.

For example, with these data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", 
"Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Data = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 
6, 11, 19, 23, 19, 13, 5, 1)), .Names = c("Month", "Data"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I can make the following bar plot

```
ggplot(dat)+ geom_bar(aes(x=  Month, y = Data), stat="identity")
```

How can I then add two vertical lines with the x-intercept of Julian day 68 and 252 using `geom_vline`?

I am not sure how to plot the lines which reference a continuous scale on the monthly (factor) x-axis data.

Comment: What days are day 68 and day 252?

Comment: Yes, I meant it would be handy if you'd said day 68 was March the whatever-it-is!

Comment: oh, yes.  sorry for not being more specific.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is plotted with a single unit per month, so you need to add the line as a fraction of the year in months, with some offset for the bar size:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Month, y = Data), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 12 * (c(68, 252) / 365) + 0.5)
```

Check this by looking at the lines for day 1 and day 365:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Month, y = Data), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 12 * (c(1, 365) / 365) + 0.5)
```

every other day will be linearly interpolated across the graph.

Answer (score 5):

When your `x` axis is a `factor`, then `geom_vline` will use the order of appearance of each value as its intercept.

You then just need to identify what fraction would correspond to the exact dates you're looking for. In this example, I'm using two illustrative fractions.

```
ggplot(dat)+ geom_bar(aes(x=  Month, y = Data), stat="identity") + 
geom_vline(xintercept = 5.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 8.7)
```

Comment: can I ask for an elaboration as the dates I need to plot will likely change in the future.

Comment: I don't think 5.2 and 9.2 correspond to the year days given.

Comment: @Spacedman I've explained in the answer these are illustrative fractions. I've seen you included a simple way to calculate the precise position of the lines, great work !